# how to solve error Number of query values and destination fields are not the same. in c# windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, insert, desktop-application

how to solve error Number of query values and destination fields are not the same. in c# windows application

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into purchase(Bill_No,Tax_Invoice_No,Date,Supplier_ID,Supplier_Name,Supplier_GST_No,Product_ID,Product_Name,Product_Type,Product_Price,Product_Qty,Amount,Gross_Total,CGST,SGST,Total,Round_Off,Final_Total,Bill_Detail) values('" + Bill_No.Text + "','" + Tax_Invoice_No.Text + "','" + Date.Text + "','" + Supplier_ID.Text + "','" + Supplier_Name.Text + "','" + Supplier_GST_No.Text + "','" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Product_ID"].Value + "','" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Product_Name"].Value +"','" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Product_Type"].Value + "','" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Product_Price"].Value + "','" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Product_Qty"].Value + "','" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Amount"].Value + "','" + Gross_Total.Text + "','" + CGST.Text + "','" + SGST.Text + "','" + Total.Text + "','" + Round_Off.Text + "','" + Final_Total.Text + "','" + Bill_Detail.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
 }
```

database table
[Click Here to View Dataabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9BjO.png)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the Database table(purchase) value are the same with your array.

afterthought: 
Query should be : Insert into purchase(table columns) values();

Comment: please check database table its same but error occurred

Comment: your insert query is not correct, missing table columns

 cmd.CommandText = "Insert into purchase(Bill_No, Tax_invoice_no,...) values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox17.Text + "',...)

NB: Try to remove spaces on your table name and name those variables(avoid using textBox1 as your variable name.

Comment: I did that you say but there was an error occurred. "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."  Please help me to solve this.

Comment: i'm waiting for your reply

Comment: Can you enter the data one by one so that you can see where the syntax error is, i dont have VS on my machine so i cant run the code